# Migrating site, only header shows

Tags: php, functions, nginx

I have copied my file structure to a new server, and exported the relevant tables to an SQL file. I have imported the tables to the new database.

When I visit the new URL, only the header of the site is showing. If I log in I can see all pages and posts.

I have tried turning php error reporting on in `wp-config.php` and `php.ini`, but nothing shows up when visiting the pages.

Any idea what could be wrong or how to troubleshoot this?

This is the latest error in the site log:

```
2012/11/01 23:17:06 [error] 23354#0: *309 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function dropdown_menu() in /home/nginx/domains/haz-ed.com.au/public/wordpress/wp-content/themes/uber/header.php on line 63" while reading upstream, client: 220.233.123.171, server: haz-ed.com.au, request: "GET /wordpress/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "haz-ed.com.au"
```

Could that be the source of the problem? What would cause this function to not be found?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP Fatal Error will halt any further output, so yes this is the reason that only the header is displayed.

Did you install the theme via FTP or did you install using the zip upload?

I'd guess that you missed some files when uploading.